# Using return in Haskell's bind operator (>>=)

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

This is the type of `>>=`:

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

It needs a function as the second argument.

And here is the type of `return`:

```
return :: Monad m => a -> m a
```

Returns `m a`

And this obviously type checks:

```
(>>) :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b
x >> y = x >>= (\_ -> y)
```

But why does the following type check and work similarly to the above code?

```
(>>) :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b
x >> y = x >>= return y
```

Here `return y` is supposed to be of type `m a` and not `a -> m a`. So why does it work?

Comment: `return` is `const` for functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're actually mixing two different monads here, that's what's happening. `x >>= return y` is in this case unified to

```
(>>) :: ∀ m a b . Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b
x >> y = x >>= (return :: m b -> a -> m b) y
       -- aka  return :: (m b) -> (a->) (m b)
```

where the `return` is implemented in the `Monad (a->)` instance:

```
instance Monad (->) a where
  return x = \_ -> x
  ...
```

It has nothing whatsoever to do with the `Monad m` instance.

As to *why* this `return` operates in the function monad: `return :: m b -> a -> m b` is inferred from the environment before the compiler ever start to reason about typeclass instances. Now, the type `m b -> a -> m b`, i.e. `m b -> (a->m b)`, has the form `mb -> amb`. The signature `return :: Monad μ => α -> μ α` therefore makes the compiler match `μ α ~ amb ~ a->m b`. Only at this point will the compiler actually choose the monad instance for `return`, and it does so by observing that `a -> m b` has indeed the form `μ α`, with `μ ~ (a->)` and `α ~ m b`. Therefore, it has to be the `(a->)` monad.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand why it typechecks given that it's using the `Monad (->) a` instance. What I still don't understand is how did it choose `Monad (->) a`? What was the logic behind it? was it simply that it was literally the only instance whose `return` would type check?

Answer (score 4):

There's a monad instance for functions and its `return` is `return x = \_ -> x` (or equivalently `return = const`).

So when you do `return y` where a function is expected, it simply picks the `return` of the function monad.